# Join three table and showing last table rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following tables:

tblData:

```
ID       Name         Email   
--------------------------------------   
1        TestName1    test@email.com
2        TestName2    test2@email.com
3        TestName3    test3@email.com
```

tblMail:

```
ID      Name             Content
------------------------------------------------
1       MailName1        Mail1 contents goes here
2       MailName2        Mail2 contents goes here
3       MailName3        Mail3 contents goes here
```

tblContacts:

```
ID      DataId      MailId
-------------------------------
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       3           1
4       3           3
```

Now i want to write a query that return following result:

```
ID      Name        Email             MailName1        MailName2        MailName3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       TestName1   test@email.com    True             True             False
2       TestName2   test2@email.com   False            False            False
3       TestName3   test3@email.com   True             False            True
```

Moreover, the `tblMail` is dynamic.. it can have more rows. so if in future i add new row that column should show in the result.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need the PIVOT function to accomplish your goal.  However, since `tblMail` is dynamic and you want a varying number of `MailNameX` columns, you will have to use dynamic sql.  Not fun, but doable.

Comment: Ya, i have tried few things with pivot but not getting is perfectly right.@DMason

Comment: Are you sure do you want to display your results that way? That means you ill get a hundred columns for hundred mails, that's not very readable. In fact you are getting a matrix NxM where n is the number of data and M the number of mails, ill not your limit your displayed results to a range of data or emails?

Comment: I agree with the above comment.  I don't see what benefit you get from expanding out the columns this way.  The data will be unusable in the UI in this format as well.  If you do want to manipulate in the UI - your best bet is to bring the data back and then shape for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the sql dynamically like this:

```
declare @mailfields nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @mailfieldselect nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @dlm nchar(1)= ''

select @mailfields=@mailfields + @dlm + N'[' + Name + N']', 
  @mailfieldselect = @mailfieldselect + @dlm + N'case when [' + Name + N'] = 0 then ''False'' else ''True'' end as ' + Name, 
  @dlm=',' 
from tblMail

select @sql ='select ID, Name, ' + @mailfieldselect + ' 
from (
  select d.ID, d.Name, m.Name as MailName 
  from tblData d 
  left join tblContacts c on d.Id=c.DataId 
  left join tblMail m on c.MailId=m.Id) f
pivot (count(MailName)
       for MailName in (' + @mailfields + ')) p'

exec (@sql)
```

I even added a SQL Fiddle example of this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c0ad/8/0